# Can we implement query dbms_stats.gather_table_stats in python3 using cx_Oracle . If yes then how?

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

Please Explain.

I am using this statement I am getting invalid SQL statement error.

```
query = "BEGIN"+"\n"+"dbms_stats.gather_table_stats("+schema_name+" , "+table_name+" , "+"cascade=>TRUE, degree=>4)\;"
query +="\n"+"END\;"

cur.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Print out `query`.  You might notice a few extra backslashes before semicolons.  And you'll see unquoted schema and table names.  The simple rewrite is:

```
query = "BEGIN"+"\n"+"dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('"+schema_name+"' , '"+table_name+"' , "+"cascade=>TRUE, degree=>4);"
query +="\n"+"END;"
```

But concatenating data into SQL is a security risk and also affects scalability.  You should use bind variables like:

```
schema_name = 'HR'
table_name = 'TESTTABLE'
query = "BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(:sn, :tn, cascade=>TRUE, degree=>4); END;"
cur.execute(query, sn=schema_name, tn=table_name)
```

Check out the cx_Oracle user guide: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html